# xmlhttp how to get the post values?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This part of an AJAX sample

```
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

**UPDATE**

How do I get the values after the equals sign from a text/input field?
What is shown above is directly written. How do I direct the input in each textarea/input field to show up after the equals signs?

If I am trying to send a bunch of text (indeterminate size) and a word, and so instead of `fname=Henry` in the above example, it could be `fname=This is a sentence` or `fname=Blue is a color of the rainbow`. Etc... value from a textarea. Do I use a variable?

If I am using jquery and I have the values... I get the values, how do I insert them into that format of `fname=value&lname=value2` just place the variables in here?

Comment: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)?

Comment: Yeah I don't know if I'm asking my question correctly, all I am trying to achieve is to send a form without the page refreshing. I don't know why, I've achieved this with uploading the coordinates/dimensions of a draggable of widgets upon releasing them/dropping. I don't know why it is different when pushing a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged jQuery so my guess is you have it available to use.

To get the values of the form you could serialize the form:

```
var data = $( "form" ).serialize();
xmlhttp.send( data );
```

Of course you will need to ensure your textarea/inputs are nested within a `form` tag.

If that doesn't have the desired effect, please post all your code including event handlers so we can inspect further.

Comment: That was it!!! Perfect! Now I have to just have to clear the field and add a notifier so I can tell that something happened but I checked the live search and the inserted content appears. Awesome! Thanks!